# Is there an Excel VBA process that can list the query-names by query-name-group?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

The Excel Data-tab, "Queries & Connections" link, opens the task pane that lists all of the query names in the workbook. In the task pane, we are allowed to assign query names to "groups". I group queries to help manage the development. I need to make an index of query-names under each of the query-groups. I haven't found any VBA or Power Query function the provides access to the group-name to which a query belongs. Likewise, in the advanced power query editor the navigation panes shows each query under the query-group-name. I have looked at queries, querytable, querytables, workbookqueries and connections objects but have not found the property listed. If I create a folder with the group name then export the connection file by group to that folder, all of the connection-files for each query in the group are exported into that folder.

Comment: any luck on the issue above? I am looking to add queries to groups, but also can't find the object in which to set this property.